# How to add a shadow and CAShapeLayer to the same UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a 6px radius to the bottom left and right corners of my view `innerView`, as well as a shadow to the whole of `innerView`. `innerView` is enclosed in a view called `view2`.

The only way I can get this to work is by using the following code:

```
let containerLayer = CALayer()
containerLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
containerLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 2)
containerLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
containerLayer.shadowRadius = 2

let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(.BottomRight), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6, height: 6)).CGPath

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath
innerView.layer.mask = maskLayer
containerLayer.addSublayer(innerView.layer)
view2.layer.addSublayer(containerLayer)
```

However, since `view2` is actually the contentView of a `UITableViewCell`, this code disables scrolling of the `UITableView` when dragging on `containerLayer`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by embedding `innerView` in another view. I applied the shadow to the new view and the radius to the `innerView`:

```
func addShadowTo(shadowView: UIView, andRadiusTo radiusView: UIView) {
     let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: radiusView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(.BottomRight), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6, height: 6)).CGPath
    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = maskPath
    shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 2)
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath
    radiusView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 :**

This Code Helped Me To Drop A Shadow To `UIVIEW` And Add CornerRadious Using `UIBezierPath`. Set Your View's Background Color As `ClearColor`

```
    yourView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear 
    let path1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:yourView.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft],
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height:  20))

    let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer1.path = path1.cgPath
    maskLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    maskLayer1.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    maskLayer1.shadowPath = maskLayer1.path
    maskLayer1.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    maskLayer1.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    maskLayer1.shadowRadius = 2
    yourView.layer.insertSublayer(maskLayer1, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout, then remove UIBezierPath. Try this code and custom one for yourself:
//This code custom a view with shadow and corner radius = 6

```
let shadowLayer: CALayer = shadowView.layer
        shadowView.clipsToBounds = false
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = 'your color'
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 3
        shadowLayer.shouldRasterize = true

        let innerLayer: CALayer = innerView.layer
        innerLayer.cornerRadius = 6
        innerView.clipsToBounds = true
        innerLayer.borderColor = 'your color'.CGColor
        innerLayer.borderWidth = 1
```

The "innerView" is inside "shadowView" (on my xib file).

Comment: This gives a radius on all corners, however, I want it only on the lower left and right corners - hence why I used the bezier path.